# Django request QueryDict Errors on pop()

Tags: python, django, django-views

Looking at dir(request.GET), I notice that pop is listed as a method.  I also believe i've popped off attributes from request in the past.

Is that accurate?  If so, why would this fail?

```
request.GET.pop('key')
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196932/15993687

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`request.GET` and `request.POST` are immutable [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) instances. This means you cannot change their attributes directly.

Copying a `QueryDict`, returns a mutable `QueryDict`. You can then call the pop method of the copy without raising an error.

```
request.GET
GET = request.GET.copy()
GET.pop('key')
```