# This QueryDict instance is immutable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Branch model with a foreign key to account (the owner of the branch):

```
class Branch(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,
                         null=True, default=None)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name','account'),)

    ...
```

I have a Account model with a foreign key to user (one to one field):

```
class Account(models.Model):
    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.create_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I've created a ModelViewSet for Branch which shows the branch owned by the logged in user:

```
class BranchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BranchSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Branch.objects.all().filter(account=self.request.user.account)
        return queryset
```

Now to create a new branch, I want to save account field with request.user.account, not with data sent from the rest client (for more security). for example:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.user_type == User.ADMIN:
        request.data['account'] = request.user.account
        return super(BranchViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    '''
        Associate branch with account
    '''
    serializer.save(account=self.request.user.account)
```

In branch serializer

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = serializers.CharField(source='account.id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'branch_alias',
              'location', 'phone', 'account')
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Branch.objects.all(),
                fields=('name', 'account')
            )
        ]
```

but I got this error:
This QueryDict instance is immutable. (means request.data is a immutable QueryDict and can't  be changed)

Do you know any better way to add additional fields when creating an object with django rest framework?

Comment: Overriding `perform_create` is the thing to do here, and does exactly what you want, so I don't know why you need to change `create` or modify the QueryDict at all.

Comment: can you show some example ?

Comment: I don't need to show an example, *you already have the right code*. Just get rid of that `create` method because what you've written in `perform_create` does exactly what you want.

Comment: but how about the data passed when calling the API ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The serializer already has the post data.

Comment: TypeError at /api/branch/
'type' object is not iterable it returns that error message

Comment: Show the full traceback please.

Comment: I fix it already

Comment: But it still returns that account is a required field.
Eventhough I added this code.
serializer.save(account=self.request.user.account)

Answer (score 96):

As you can see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

> The **QueryDicts** at **request.POST** and **request.GET** will be immutable when accessed in a *normal request/response cycle*.

so you can use the recommendation from the same documentation:

> To get a mutable version you need to use **QueryDict.copy()**

or ... use a little trick, for example, if you need **to keep a reference** to an object for some reason or leave the object the same:

```
# remember old state
_mutable = data._mutable

# set to mutable
data._mutable = True

# сhange the values you want
data['param_name'] = 'new value'

# set mutable flag back
data._mutable = _mutable
```

where data it is your **QueryDicts**

Answer (score 22):

Do Simple:

```
#views.py
from rest_framework import generics


class Login(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializerClass
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data._mutable = True
        request.data['username'] = "example@mail.com"
        request.data._mutable = False

#serializes.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class MySerializerClass(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

Comment: request.data._mutable = True did it for me

Comment: I got an error ```'dict' object has no attribute '_mutable'
```

Comment: @mecdeality, This should be happening when the request method is NOT GET or POST I believe

Answer (score 10):

```
request.data._mutable=True
```

Make mutable true to enable editing in querydict or the request.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `request=request.copy()` at the first line of your function.

Comment: maybe you meant `request=request.data.copy()` - @ShreyashSrivsatava

Comment: Yes, right, silly me :/
Or simply, `data=request.data.copy()`

Answer (score 3):

> Do you know any better way to add additional fields when creating an object with django rest framework?

The official way to provide extra data when creating/updating an object is to pass them to the `serializer.save()` as shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)

Comment: this is not helpful when attributes are needed for validation. `is_valid()` is called before `.save()`

Comment: If they are needed by validation and not provided by the client you should consider adding an extra step which would be "business validation" or something similar. Not a good idea to put too much business logic in the serializer.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think it would be more elegant to write code like this.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = OrderedDict()
    data.update(request.data)
    data['account'] = request.user.account
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Great answer. Any special reason why you chose to select OrderedDict instead of regular dict?

Comment: Because the default implementation of request._data in drf is of type QueryDict, dict is fine in this example, but bugs may occur in other cases.

[Request._data](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/df92e57ad6c8394ca54654dfc7a2722f822ed8c8/rest_framework/request.py#L360)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

> The QueryDicts at request.POST and request.GET will be immutable when accessed in a normal request/response cycle. To get a mutable version you need to use QueryDict.copy().