# Is it safe to attempt to edit request.data in Django REST Framework 3.13.1?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a DRF view function (with an `@api_view(["POST"])` decorator) to use user posted data to create a new database record for a model `Product`. I have in my model definition `Meta` `unique_together = ["user", "name"]`. I would like to ensure that this unique together constraint is checked in a serializer validation itself, so as to avoid raising an integrity error at the time of saving.

So what I used to try earlier was `request.data["user"] = request.user.id`, before passing `request.data` to the model serializer, then calling `serializer.is_valid()`, and finally `serializer.save()`. However, this used to raise some error to the effect that `request.data` was not modifiable when I was using some DRF 3.12.x (and Django 3.2). This was a minor inconvenience as I had to create a copy of `request.data` to modify the posted data. This kind of thing is described in multiple places, for e.g., [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717442/this-querydict-instance-is-immutable) and [elsewhere](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf-request/).

But I have since upgraded to DRF 3.13.1 and I noticed that now I am able to modify `request.data` in ways that I was not able to earlier (adding a new key-value pair, popping or editing the value for an existing key). I am testing using Postman: the type of `request.data` showed as `QueryDict` when I posted using form data, and `dict` when I posted json. In either case, I am able to modify it.

Is this allowed in DRF now? And, is this safe to do or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: FWIW, the integrity error is the only *real* check you have in the end. Whatever you do before saving to the database, in race condition situations, the integrity check is the only thing that counts and you must be prepared to handle it either way.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for this. But could you say if it is safe to edit request.data?