# Django: How to get a muttable object from get_object_or_404 in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm using Django==4.2 and after using `get_object_or_404` function in my view I get an immutable object.

```
result = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
```

And I need to pass this "result" to my form (in post method):

```
request.POST["result"] = result
```

However, on post I'm getting this error:

**`This QueryDict instance is immutable`**

I've tried to do something like

```
result = result.copy()
```

to make it mutable but it didn't work.

So, what should I do to make the "result" mutable, so I can pass it to the form?

Thanks!

Comment: see if the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717442/this-querydict-instance-is-immutable) works.

Comment: Can you show the view and form? Perhaps you should be using a ModelForm?

Comment: Can we see the whole code? This is hard to debug without that data. Honestly your code here looks off so I'd like to see the whole idea you are trying to implement. `request.POST["result"] = result` -- I can't figure out why you are doing this, forms allow you to query and then based on a forms `POST` data you should be seeing if you can get the object with `get_object_or_404`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, the request.POST QueryDict is immutable by design to prevent accidental modification of form data. If you need to include additional data, including your result object, you should use a different dictionary, such as request.POST.copy() or a new dictionary altogether.

Here's how you can achieve that:

```
result = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)

# Make a mutable copy of request.POST
mutable_post = request.POST.copy()

# Add your result to the mutable_post dictionary
mutable_post["result"] = result

# Now use the mutable_post dictionary in your form
my_form = MyForm(mutable_post)
```

This way, you're not modifying the original request.POST but creating a mutable copy and adding your result to it.

Make sure to handle the form validation and processing appropriately after creating the form instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy